# Do search and replace on commands from terminal history

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I would like to know how/if I can reuse a command from my terminal history, but in a modified version. Here's an example:

```
$ filter_script file2 > output_file2
$ # ...
# now run the same command, but replace '2' with '4'
$ filter_script file4 > output_file4
```

This is a very simple example, and of course I can simply access the command from the history and manually replace the two `2`s, but is there a more elegant way?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If there's only *one* instance of whatever it is you want replaced, `bash(1)` has an easy feature first introduced in `csh(1)`:

```
^old^new
```

will replace the first instance of `old` with `new`:

```
$ filter_script file2 > output_file2
$ ^2^4
filter_script file4 > output_file2
```

If you want to replace *all* the instances, that requires more typing:

```
$ filter_script file2 > output_file2
$ !:gs/2/4/
filter_script file4 > output_file4
```

The `g` specifies the *global* replacement on the command line. The `!` refers to a line from history -- which could be more specific, if you wanted to pull a command from further back in history that the immediately previous command. See `bash(1)`'s section on `Event Designators`.